# How to cut off power supply if Input voltage is greater than 12Vdc and less than 7.2 Vdc

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

I need help here is the diagram that I followed. In this diagram, the supply will cut off if the Vin is less than 6.5Vdc. Now I want to cut off if the supply voltage is less than 7.2V and greater than 12V. Is this possible?

[image]

I found this on https://www.electroschematics.com/78xx-voltage-regulator
Any help would gladly be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That supply will not switch off on low voltage, the output voltage will regulate until the input gets down to about 7 volts. Below that the output will be input - 2 V or so. It would be much better if you edit your question to explain what problem you're trying to solve rather than have us trying to fix your solution.

Comment: The short answer is no there is no good way to do that without adding more components. Look at "hot-swaps" they are going to make your life easier.

Comment: It can easily be done with an MCU, is it possible for you to use an MCU like Arduino?

Comment: No I dont rely on arduino systems. I will just look for a component to do that kind of job. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are special IC available e. g. from Analog, Maxim or TI for that purpose. Look for "Overvoltage Undervoltage Protection" or similar.